# Фильтрация JSON объектов Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular2

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться :)

 
Есть JSON, который получаю с сервера:

```
public getProduct(){
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/product/')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.products = data;
                console.log(this.products);
                return this.products;
            });
}
```

Данные (products) приходят в следующем виде (которых больше 100):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "treaty_number": "qwerty",
        "insurant_name": "LAVERS",
        "belonging_to_the_holding_company": "company_holding",
        "beneficiary": "beneficiary",
        "insurance_type": "ОСАГО",
        "insurance_object": "BMW",
        "address_reg_signs": "reg",
        "register_sign": null,
        "vin": "vin_number",
        "fio": null,
        "address_object": null,
        "chassis_number": null,
        "id_number_ship": null,
        "data_start": "2017-07-13",
        "data_end": "2018-07-12",
        "days_left": 330,
        "days_left_before_the_next_payment": null,
        "insurers_name": "insurers_company",
        "tarif": "5.00",
        "CC": "1370000.00",
        "CP": "72074.00",
        "franchise": "15000",
        "date_of_receipt_d_s": "2017-07-09",
        "KB": null,
        "size_KB": null,
        "prolongation": True,
    },
```

Стоит задача вывести данные в шаблон (2 колонки, т.к. только два одинаковых словаря могут встретиться), если у них: 
1) Одинаковые идентификаторы (или) address_reg_signs || register_sign || vin || fio || chassis_number || id_number_ship 
2) Одинаковый "insurant_name"  
3) Одинаковый "insurance_type" 
4) "prolongation" в True 
И вывести два совпадающих словаря с этими данными.

Так же нужно как-то учитывать (вводятся две даты) временной диапазон и по нему профильтровать, с условиями, которые выше.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь! Спасибо.

**UPDATE** 
Фильтрация по insurant_name

```
tmp = '';
tmps = [];

public appendContent(){
  this.tmps = [];
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/api/product/')
            .map((response: Response) => response.json())
            .subscribe(data=>{
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].insurant_name == this.selectedInsurant) {
                this.tmp = data[i];
                this.tmps.push(this.tmp);
            }
        } 
   }); 
 }
```

typescript: 2.4.1

Comment: А в чём проблема? Вы не понимаете как написать условия фильтров? Или как вызвать функцию фильтрации?

Comment: @SergeyRogachev
Не совсем понимаю, как фильтры по условию написать и вывести два этих словаря в шаблон. 
Добавил функцию фильтрации по insurant_name. (см. update)

Comment: Ну собственно, вы движетесь в правильном направлении. Я бы предложил почитать про функцию ``filter``. Ну а условия вы сами описали, так что я не думаю, что будут проблемы с написанием кода по ним.